# How to get "Sign in with Twitter" working with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, oauth

Im trying to implement Sing In with Twitter working, however i keep getting the following error

> Whoa there!
>   The request token for this page is invalid. It may have already been used, or expired because it is too old. Please go back to the site or application that sent you here and try again; it was probably just a mistake.

Here's my code, the what am I doing wrong?

```
// Server
var OAuth = require('oauth').OAuth;
var callbackUrl = null;
var oa = new OAuth(
    'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token',
    'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token',
    CONSUMER_KEY,
    CONSUMER_SECRET,
    '1.0',
    callbackUrl,
    'HMAC-SHA1'
);

const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    oa.getOAuthRequestToken(function(error, token, secret, results) {
        resolve({
            token,
            secret,
        });
    });
});

var oauth = await promise;
return { oauth };

// Client
window.open(`https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=${twitter.oauth.token})`);
```

I've also set the callback url to the same as what I have in the app details page, but no dice!

```
var callbackUrl = 'http://0.0.0.0:3001/settings/social/twitter/oauth';
```

Small note, not sure if it helps, but I've noticed the returned tokens are shorter than the examples I've seen online. Example:

```
Mine: EBhy3AAAAAAA94TPAAABajDwCww%
Twitter Site: NPcudxy0yU5T3tBzho7iCotZ3cnetKwcTIRlX0iwRl0&
```

Comment: Is that an error response from `oa.getOAuthRequestToken` or from something you're doing inside its callback?

Comment: I take the token that comes back and go to the url specified and I get the error there:
https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=Oo_i4AAAAAAA94TPAAABajDVO_k)

As per their documentation https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/log-in-with-twitter/guides/implementing-sign-in-with-twitter

Comment: Don't you think then it would be important to show us that code?

Comment: Sorry about that @IsaacVidrine i guess since there's really not much to it on that side I didn't think to! I've updated the original post

Comment: LOL @IsaacVidrine thank you so much... If you look at that redirect code, turns out I had an extra ")" in the path... Thank you so much for making me look at that =D

Comment: Glad you got it workin haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My client code had an extra ")"

```
window.open(`https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=${twitter.oauth.token})`);
```

should read

```
window.open(`https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=${twitter.oauth.token}`);
```